# How to count the number of changes in column (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c('black','white','green','red','brown', 'blue'),
                 Num=c(1,1,1,0,1,0))
```

How many times 1 changed to 0 in the column Num? How I can count it by R?

Comment: `sum(diff(df$Num)==-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `head`, `tail` and count instances where the previous value was 1 and current value is 0.

```
sum(head(df$Num, -1) == 1 & tail(df$Num, -1) == 0)
#[1] 2
```

---

Using the same logic with `dplyr` `lead`/`lag` we can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  filter(Num == 0 & lag(Num) == 1) %>%  nrow()

df %>%  filter(Num == 1 & lead(Num) == 0) %>% nrow()
```

Comment: it works! is it possible to count number of combinations? For example, "1,1,1" - 1 times and "1" - 1 times

Comment: @Denis `rle` could be better in such cases. Something like `sum(with(rle(df$Num), lengths >= 3 & values == 1))` to count 3 consecutive 1's.

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `rle` from `base R`

```
sum(rle(df$Num)$values)
#[1] 2
```

---

Or with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nrow(setDT(df)[, .N[any(Num > 0)] , rleid(Num)])
#[1] 2
```